# Apache Ignite. Identify transactions by application

Tags: transactions, ignite, diagnostics

A team uses Apache Ignite massively. Faced a problem how to identify the external app modules which keep transactions open in a grid.
Is there a parameter on Ignite transaction to (ala MODULE in Oracle) which can be set on a client side?
Are there other ways to manage such a situation?

Thanks in advance,
Alexey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be discussed on Apache Ignite developers list: http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Identifying-grid-transactions-td22947.html